# JAXB: unmarshall and modify mixed content

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have started to learn Java from JAXB library. My aim is to unmarshall and modify JATS XML, which has a lot of mixed content. Actually, if simplify, XML looks like this:

```
<article>
  <body>
    <sec>
      <title>text</title>
      <list></list>
      <sec><p></p></sec>
      <p>
        text
        <junk>text</junk>
        <morejunk>text</morejunk>
      </p>
      <anotherjunkcontent>text</anotherjunkcontent>
    </sec>
  </body>
</article>
```

I have already managed to generate classes from xsd. For element, such as `article` or `body` getting and setting id, content etc is fairly easy. But how I can get and modify data inside `sec` or `p` elements, that have mixed content?

For example, part of code from autogenerated Sec class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "sec")
public class Sec {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "list", type = com.emedjournal.objects.List.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "p", type = P.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "sec", type = Sec.class, required = false),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "title", type = Title.class, required = false)
    })
    protected java.util.List<Object> content;

    public java.util.List<Object> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }
```

And my part of code, that unmarshall and marshall this xml:

```
public class transformMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarhsaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Article article = (Article) unmarhsaller.unmarshal(new File("article.xml"));

        Body elementBody = article.getBody();
        List<Sec> listSec = elementBody.getSec();

        for (Sec eSec : listSec) {
            List<Object> listObjectsInSec = eSec.getContent();
            for (Object insideList : listObjectsInSec) {
            //ToDO something here to get content, modify it and put it back
            //System.out.println(insideList);
            }

        }
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.marshal(article, new File("article2.xml"));
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); 
    }
}
```

How can I manage it? The line `System.out.println(insideList);`gives me a list of objects, like `...objects.Title@4f6f416f` or `...objects.P@3b8f0a79`. How I can retrieve data from them? toString() or String.valueOf() are not working in this case, maybe because they are not have values, that can be expressed as strings. I am not experienced in programming, so maybe it is something obvious?

Comment: JAXB is mostly useful when you want to serialize an object to XML and then back (like webservices for example). XML is too broad to be managed conveniently by JAXB. 
I don't say it's impossible, but you will probably end up with something difficult to use, and nearly impossible to update. 
You should rely on DOM , SAX or Stax when documents allow mixed content or ANY.

Comment: I have tried to work with DOM and XPath. For me the idea to work with objects looks better, than with node elements. Hope I will find good solution with JAXB.

Comment: you can use `instanceOf` to find the object that it can be cast to. And then cast it to that `object` to retrieve the values.